# List comprehension to return highest value

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, list-comprehension

I'm scraping a web page and I need to know how many pages there is to scrape. It is as following:

```
<div class="pagination">
    <a href="/travel__world-desktop-wallpapers/page/2">2</a>
    <a href="/travel__world-desktop-wallpapers/page/3">3</a>
    <a href="/travel__world-desktop-wallpapers/page/4">4</a>
    ...
    <a href="/travel__world-desktop-wallpapers/page/31">31</a>
    <a href="/travel__world-desktop-wallpapers/page/32">32</a>
    <a href="/travel__world-desktop-wallpapers/page/33">33</a>
    <a href="/travel__world-desktop-wallpapers/page/2">Next »</a>
</div>
```

how can I set up a list comprehension that returns me the highest number of pages( in this case, 33)?

Comment: Why do you think a list comprehension is appropriate for this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. You set up a generator expression instead:

```
max(int(link.text) 
    for link in soup.find('div', class_='pagination').find_all('a')
    if link.text.strip().isdigit())
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <div class="pagination">
...     <a href="/travel__world-desktop-wallpapers/page/2">2</a>
...     <a href="/travel__world-desktop-wallpapers/page/3">3</a>
...     <a href="/travel__world-desktop-wallpapers/page/4">4</a>
...     ...
...     <a href="/travel__world-desktop-wallpapers/page/31">31</a>
...     <a href="/travel__world-desktop-wallpapers/page/32">32</a>
...     <a href="/travel__world-desktop-wallpapers/page/33">33</a>
...     <a href="/travel__world-desktop-wallpapers/page/2">Next »</a>
... </div>
... ''')
>>> max(int(link.text) for link in soup.find('div', class_='pagination').find_all('a') if link.text.strip().isdigit())
33
```

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Someone appears to be in a downvoting mood these past few days.

Comment: It is really an elegant solution. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Ive found that that is often counterproductive to a downvoters goal since you almost always get at least one compensating up-vote (which is worth more than the griefers downvote :/)

Comment: Just one small thing... when a page just have one page, I get an error: "ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence" how can I get around this?

Comment: @XVirtusX: You could just catch the exception in a `try:`, `except ValueError:`. It's the easiest alternative, in any case; the other being an explicit test for matching numbered-links first in a list comprehension.